Blazor QuickGrid TemplateColumn is giving a compile error
I am newbie with QuickGrid and .Net-8.
I get this error for the Blazor QuickGrid .net-8.

Error (active)    CS1061  'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for
'Year' and no accessible extension method 'Year' accepting a first
argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using
directive or an assembly reference?)

I really don't understand the error text, and don't know how to fix this error.  Can this be fixed?  Thanks.
The QuickGrid works perfectly for the PropertyColumns.  However, the above error appears during compilation for the TemplateColumn shown below.
<PropertyColumn Property="f => f.DT_END"   Format="MM/dd/yyyy" Title="End Date" Sortable="false"/>
<TemplateColumn>
   <div>
      <span>@(_FilteredVehicles.First(r => r.UID_VEHICLE == context.UID_VEHICLE).DT_END!.Year.ToString())</span>
   </div>
</TemplateColumn>

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
After the above compilation error no longer appears, thanks to @MisterMagoo, I now get this error that I do not understand.

Error (active)    RZ9999  The child content element 'ChildContent' of
component 'TemplateColumn' uses the same parameter name ('context') as
enclosing child content element 'ChildContent' of component
'AuthorizeView'. Specify the parameter name like: ' to resolve the ambiguity


Regarding the second error...I found an SO answer that points out the solution -- to rename the 'context" of the 'AuthorizeView' to
<AuthorizeView Roles="FCI, Admin,Manager" Context="authContext">

Hope this SO solution helps.
Component 'EditForm' uses the same parameter name ('context') as enclosing child content element 'Authorized'

It looks like DT_END is Nullable, the equivalent of Nullable<DateTime> - which means you need to get the Value either explicitly
DT_END.Value.Year - which could throw an exception
or by using the null conditional operator
DT_END?.Year which is what I recommend for you here.

Thank you -- the DT_END?.Year allowed compilation.  However, I now get this error that I do not understand. Can you please help me understand? Error (active) RZ9999 The child content element 'ChildContent' of component 'TemplateColumn' uses the same parameter name ('context') as enclosing child content element 'ChildContent' of component 'AuthorizeView'. Specify the parameter name like: ' to resolve the ambiguity
